# how to implement an interface method change in more that 50 classes

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface `IMyInterface`, which currently have only one member method `MyMethod1` having return type void. I have this interface in more than 50 classes, now suppose I change the return type of the interface method from `void` to `string`.

How to change the method signature in all the classes implementing the interface. 
I know Visual studio IDE does that with option to replace all. Just curious to know if there is any other method.

Comment: That is a breaking change, no tool is magically going to write code for you that now produces the required *string* return value.  Or use it.  Other than the tool you have between your ears.

Comment: I agree its a breaking change and the tool will not resolve it completely. I will have to manually do that with little help from VS IDE - that my question / curiosity - is there any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just change the method signature in the interface, and follow all the error messages you get.

After all, in each method you're going to need to decide what to return, so you should really look at each of those classes individually. You may well find that refactoring tools would offer the option of changing the signature and adding a a `return null;` statement at the end of each method, but I'd say that that aspect of the change is likely to take far less effort than really working out what each implementation should return - and if you do it all manually, you're less likely to accidentally leave one implementation with that "default" (quite possibly inappropriate) return.

Comment: I know, this aspect is less and should is not good design practice, but in real life scenarios this might be possible and  that wjhat the refactoring tools help us to do.. I had a similar experience in my project - where I had to the resharper tool to fix the issue.. but was curious to know if any other solution.

Comment: @hpatel02: I really didn't follow that, I'm afraid. My point is that if you automate things, you're less likely to put time into thinking about the change you're making, which may well be best implemented differently in each class.

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio a *replace all* is the only solution. But [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will allow you to do that.

Comment: You mentione Resharper in your question? Are you sure?

Comment: no Visual Studio I mentioned in my question - see my other comments

Answer (score 0):

You can download [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It has an option to refactor signature. It's not free, but you can get a free 30 day trial.

[image]